# .Net Core MSAL Authentication for Azure Function App Web API

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-ad-msal, azure-function-app

I have a Azure Function App that is written in C# .net Core

I use `Microsoft.Identity.Client;` library to do this authentication proccess.

In my Function App API, I make another call to Time Series Insights (TSI), so I must use the accessToken passed into the Function App to grab a new token for scope of TSI.

There are two main flows that need to be working, but I can only get one version to work.

The **working** version is getting a token in PostMan and Authenticating to the API

```
IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
            .Create(clientId)
            .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
            .WithTenantId(tenantId)
            .Build();
confidentialClientApplication.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync();
```

> 

The **NOT** working flow - where the User is signed into my website and calls the API from the website. Then I must use the

```
UserAssertion userAssertion = new UserAssertion(accessToken);
confidentialClientApplication.AcquireTokenOnBehalfOf(scopes, userAssertion).ExecuteAsync();
```

The `AcquireTokenOnBehalfOf` works for me until the token is expired in the Cache. I am using the Azure Token Store in the Function App Authentication.

The website gets a token similarly to PostMan, and then calls the Function App API. That much is working, but then the token is expired. The documentation says that to use the token store a silent request can be used to refresh the token (`AcquireTokenSilent`) - but that does not make sense to me since I do not have an `IAccount` to use for `confidentialClientApplication.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, acount)`

What is the correct way or a better way to have both options available for authenticating while using the built-in Function App Token Store in Azure Portal?

Answer (score 0):

The On-Behalf-Of flow doesn't support refresh token, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-authentication-flows#how-each-flow-emits-tokens-and-codes).

[image]

If you would like to use this flow, you need to authenticate again to renew the access token.